# Working with kerning commands in token lists

Tags: expl3, xparse, kerning

I have written some commands that are supposed to simplify the typesetting of derivations from a formal grammar.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l__inft_gr_vars_seq
\seq_new:N \l__inft_gr_alph_seq

\keys_define:nn { inft / gr }
{   
  variables .code:n = { \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__inft_gr_vars_seq { #1 } },
  alphabet  .code:n = { \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__inft_gr_alph_seq { #1 } }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \DefineGrammar { m }
{
  \keys_set:nn { inft / gr } { #1 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \GrammarDrv { m }
{
  \inft_grammar_drv:n { #1 }
}

\cs_new:Nn \inft_grammar_drv:n
{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { => } { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq
    { \exp_not:n { \inft_word:nn { \width} { ##1 } } }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { \Rightarrow }
}

\cs_new:Nn \inft_char:nn
{
  \makebox[#1]
  { 
    \str_case_x:nnF { \tl_to_str:n {#2} }
    {
      { ##                } { \texttt{\#}            }
      { \c_underscore_str } { \scalebox{.87}{$\Box$} }
      { \c_tilde_str      } { $\varepsilon$          }
      {                   } { $\varepsilon$          }
    }
    { \texttt{#2} }
  }
}

\cs_new:Nn \inft_word:nn
{
  \tl_if_blank:nTF {#2}
  {
    \inft_char:nn { #1 } { }
  }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tempa {#2}
    \tl_map_inline:Nn \l_tempa 
    {   
      \seq_if_in:NnTF \l__inft_gr_vars_seq ##1
      { 
        \inft_gr_var:n { ##1 } 
      }
      {
        \seq_if_in:NnTF \l__inft_gr_alph_seq ##1
        {  
          \inft_char:nn { #1 } { ##1 } 
        }
        {
          { ##1 }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

\cs_new:Nn \inft_gr_var:n
{
  \tl_if_single:nTF { #1 }
    { #1          }
    { \mathit{#1} }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\DefineGrammar{variables = {S, X, Y, Z}, alphabet = {a, b, c}}

\par (1) $\GrammarDrv{S => aXYZ}$ 
\par (2) $\GrammarDrv{S => aXY{{\kern-1.7pt}}Z}$ 
\par (3) $\GrammarDrv{S => aXY{\kern-1.7pt}Z}$ 

\end{document}
```

The output

[image: Output of the MWE]

shows that (1) manual kerning is required as long as specific rules are not  implemented, (2) the kerning command works correctly if it is "protected" by two pairs of braces, (3) the kerning command breaks if it is surrounded by only one pair of braces.

How do I have to modify my commands such that (3) works as desired?

Comment: The second argument of `\seq_if_in:NnTF` is of type `n` hence should be braced `\seq_if_in:NnTF \l__.._seq { ##1 }`.

Comment: but also why are you boxing every character (which means you are not using math mode at all, and lose any font-specified kerns, which is why you need the hand correction

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right that I have to rethink the whole design. I have introduced the boxing because, in some other cases, I need characters with a fixed width (see first parameter of the command). I will need to remove the boxing from the character formatting and implement it only where really needed. What I have shown here is only a small part of a growing package for typesetting theoretical informatics stuff (formal languages, grammars, automatons and much more).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle On the other hand, automatic kerning does not seem to work in math mode. Consider, e.g., the example `$XYZ$`, in which, in my opinion, the space between `Y` and `Z` is too large. I think I have seen other questions and answers regarding this topic.

Comment: @Matthias if it is a word you want `$\mathit{XYZ}$` if it is a consecutive list of separate variables you want `$XYZ$` where TeX adds positive kerns to ensure they are separate `\OML/cmm/m/it/10 X \kern0.7847 \OML/cmm/m/it/10 Y \kern2.22223 \OML/cmm/m/it/10 Z`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered by [Manuel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/21930/) in his comment above.

In lines 61 and 66, the second argument `##1` of `\seq_if_in:NnTF` must be braced because it is of type `n`. The corrected versions are

```
\seq_if_in:NnTF \l__inft_gr_vars_seq { ##1 }
```

and

```
\seq_if_in:NnTF \l__inft_gr_alph_seq { ##1 }
```

respectively.

[image: Output of the corrected MWE]